# PHP Get Names Of Aliased Traits

Tags: php

I have a few aliased traits in PHP like so:

```
class Foo {
    use Bar, Other {
        Bar as One;
        Bar as Two;
        Other as Three;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get a list of the currently used traits and their aliased names for that class? I know PHP has class_uses(), but that only returns Bar and Other not One, Two or Three in the example above. I'd like to have a key => value of the Original name and the aliased name. Anyone happen to know how? I've done a lot of googling with no results.

Comment: Had a look at PHP's source code. After the alias has been registered, PHP doesn't know about what is the original and what is the alias. Like hardlinking in file system.

Comment: @Hiphop03199 - Presuming that's true, that actually blows chunks. How hard is it to keep a freaking record of what you mapped where PHP ><

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.gettraitaliases.php maybe?

Comment: @jszobody - Please submit that as an answer. It worked and I'd like to accept your answer for credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can use `ReflectionClass` to get this. Specifically the `getTraitAliases` method:

http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.gettraitaliases.php